# Get titles from Wikipedia

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am kinda new to Angular.
I am trying to get 4 titles from Wikipedia API, but i can't figure up what's wrong in my code
this is the eample URL for 1 title
example URL = `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageprops&format=json&titles=Wilson_Lumpkin`

### model

IwikiItem.ts:

```
export interface IWikiItem {
  batchcomplete?: string;
  query?: Query;
}

export interface Query {
  normalized?: Normalized[];
  pages?: Pages;
}

export interface Normalized {
  from?: string;
  to?: string;
}

export interface Pages {
  id?: The4101295;
}

export interface The4101295 {
  pageid?: number;
  ns?: number;
  title?: string;
  pageprops?: Pageprops;
}

export interface Pageprops {
  defaultsort?: string;
  page_image_free?: string;
  wikibase_item?: string;
}
```

### Component

```
private titles = [
 'Wilson_Lumpkin',
 'Robert Toombs',
 'Saxby Chambliss',
 'Wyche Fowler',
];

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<IWikiItem>;
constructor(private srv: SrvService) {
    this.titles.forEach((name) => {
      this.srv
        .getWiki('action=query&prop=pageprops&format=json&titles=' + name)
        .subscribe((data) => {
          console.log(data.query),
          (this.dataSource: new MatTableDataSource<IWikiItem[data]>);
            (err) => {
              console.log(err);
            };
        });
    });
  }
}
```

### service

```
export class SrvService {
  readonly base_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?';

  getWiki(title: string) {
    return this.http.get<IWikiItem>(this.base_url + title);
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
}
```

What's wrong here? i am, getting this error in console:
[error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCJtw.png)

### Edit 1

I am getting an error this.handle eror.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVIGt.png)

Comment: You likely want to url encode the name

Comment: can you please provide an example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript

Comment: i have tested it, its not working- same errors

Comment: Code seems fine... Do other urls work?

Comment: same errors with other Wikipedia url's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess `Wikipedia APis` does not support `CORS`. So instead of normal http request, you need t make a `jsonp` request.

For `jsonp` request you need to import module `HttpClientJsonpModule` in your application.
After that you can make the request like below.

[Reference Link](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-jsonp-request)

```
 getWiki(title: string) {
    const url = this.base_url + title;
    return this.http.jsonp(url, 'callback').pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError) // then handle the error
    );
  }

  callback(response) {
    console.log("response", response);
  }

  handleError(error){
    console.log(error);
  }
```

Working sample [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-rgb-4tciu?file=/src/app/data.service.ts)

Comment: Great! thanks. can you please write error handle best practice for that function?

Comment: you can refer this document for the same [Link](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-jsonp-request) Please accept the answer if this solve your problem.

Comment: i am getting an error, `this.handleError` - Argument of type '(error: HttpErrorResponse) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<IWikiItem>) => ObservableInput<any>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'

Comment: Check this [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-rgb-4tciu?file=/src/app/data.service.ts) No able to reproduce, Can you share your source code?